# implement <img src = "in a variable that contains multiple urls

Tags: php, regex, image, variables

Hello i want to implement `<img src ="` in a variable that contains multiple urls. Here the code i use :

```
echo '<b>'.$d->SyndicObjectName.'</b>'.'<br>'.$d->DetailDescriptif.'<br>'.$d->ListingPhoto.'<br>'.$d->DetailPhoto.'<br> Capacit&eacute; min/max : '.$d->DetailCapacitemin.'/'.$d->DetailCapacitemax.'<br>'.$d->DetailSiteweb
                .'<br>'.$d->DetailMail.'<br>'.$d->DetailTelephone.'<br> Detail confort : '.$d->DetailConfort.'<br>'.'Animaux accept&eacute; : '.$d->ListingAnimauxacceptes.'<br> Activit&eacute;s possibles : '.$d->DetailActivites.'<br> Services : '.$d->DetailServices
                .'<br> Descriptif habitation : '.$d->DetailDescriptifhabitation;

            echo '<hr>';
```

$d->DetailPhoto contains image url list like this :

> CDT22-tfinal-111514_4.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_5.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_1.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_3.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_10.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_9.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_7.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_11.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_6.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_8.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_2.jpg|111514|CDT22-tfinal-111514_6.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514_5.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514_9.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514_1.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514_8.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514_3.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514_10.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514_11.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514_4.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514_2.jpg||111514||##CDT22-tfinal-111514_7.jpg||111514||

The question is, how can i do to add `<img scr="` around these urls ?

Comment: depending on what format it is (seems like a string), extract the actual url's from the rest of the data (explode, regex, etc) and loop over them to display each image.

Comment: You will need a separate `<img>` tag for each image

Comment: explode on pipe, loop

Comment: Do you want/expect to have image tags for the entries such as `##CDT22-tfinal-111514.jpg`?  Also, what is the purpose of the numbers between the image filenames?

Comment: numbers between the image filenames can be use as alt="" or can be removed.. I need somehting like <img src="CDT22-tfinal-111514_7.jpg"> for each image without #. I'm kind of noob with php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is basically what you would need. I even considered the places with two pipes.

```
$supported_image = array(
    'gif',
    'jpg',
    'jpeg',
    'png'
);
$images = array();
$images = explode('|', $d->DetailPhoto); //Will explode a single string in many values in a array, those values are the ones between pipes |

foreach ($images as $imgsrc)
{
    $ext = strtolower(pathinfo($imgsrc, PATHINFO_EXTENSION)); //Gets the extension from the image.
    if(in_array($ext, $supported_image)) //Checks if the current string contains a valid image extension.
    {
       $pic = str_replace('#','',$imgsrc); //Removes ## from the filename.
       echo "<img src='$pic'></img> <br>";
    }
}
```

It will check if the string contains a file extension, then echo it as an img tag.

You can increase the supported images extensions, in case you need another format.

In my test, this is what it generated:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to output an `img` tag from each of the `.jpg` entries in that list that do not start with `#` (with a line-break between them), the following will work.

```
foreach(explode("|", $d->DetailPhoto) as $img)
{
    if(strpos($img, ".jpg") !== false && strpos($img, "#") !== 0)
    {
        echo "<img src=\"$img\"/><br/>";
    }
}
```